# Shopping cart for existing website

Tags: html, drupal, paypal, shopping-cart

I'd like to get some opinions for adding a shopping cart to an existing website.  I have created several html5 websites but not an ecommerce site.  I have been asked to add an online shop (for pick up only, not deliveries) to a vets site.  I was looking at ubercart on Drupal but from what I have read, you can only add that to an existing Drupal website (mine is not).

Whether the online shop is added as a subdomain or another folder on the server makes no difference.

All suggestions appreciated.  Payment can be PayPal or any other reputable company.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that Drupal is what you really want then my advice is to use Drupal with Drupal commerce module (set of modules). And actually you would need to set up Drupal with Drupal Commerce and add your static pages to that site, not opposite way. :)
You can find some Drupal with preinstalled Drupal Commerce which may make your life a bit easier.

However it's not just a "shopping cart" as you say (not sure what that means actually), but a whole e-commerce solution, which can be a overkill for someone that is not familiar with Drupal.